# What do Hilbert and Bernays mean when they say "finitist number theory"?

Tags: soft-question

Perhaps it is not a fair question to be addressed here. Anyway, when I read that Hilbert and Bernays develop finitist number theory. What does "finitist number theory" mean here?

Comment: Related to this, maybe? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitism

Comment: A bit general. It´s closer to
primitive recursive arithmetic, it seems.

Comment: Historically, Hilbert had methods in mind that avoid completed infinities, something, that would satisfy an intuitionist. But of course it's a notion like "elementary proof of the RH", you'll recognize it when you see it, but it's hard to say very precisely in advance what exactly it means.

Comment: Also, the details of Hilbert's philosophical ideas changed quite a bit over the course of his life, so he might have given different answers to your question depending on when exactly you asked him. (HB of course is post-Gödel.)

Comment: Thanks Christian. Yes, HB wanted to sketch a finitist consistency proofs for strong formal theories. I´ve never heard about finitist NT, must I admit.

Comment: I think it might help if you say *where* you read this.

Answer (score 4):

I think the standard reference on this question is W. W. Tait, Finitism, *Journal of Philosophy* **78** (1981), 524-546.